# Local notification contents: subtitle or body not showing [Swift 5]

Tags: swift, xcode, notifications, alert, uilocalnotification

I have previously had local notifications working in my app that show just a title. Now I would like to have a subtitle and body for each notification. I added a `subtitle` and `body` for my `UNMutableNotificationContent`. But when the notification presents itself, the subtitle or body is not there. **How can I fix this?**

Here's how I add a local notification:

```
        let content      = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title    = "title works!"
        content.subtitle = "testing subTitle"
        content.body = "testing body"
        content.sound    = .default

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

        let identifier = "notificationId"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Hey listen! Error adding notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("saved notification")
            }
        }
```

Here is how I ask for notification permissions:

```
private func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Hey listen! Got an error requesting notification authorization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {

                if granted {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("not granted")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my `willPresent` code:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the case of receiving the local notification in the foreground or in the background?

If it is in the foreground, you would be using `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` and in that case if you want an alert, you need to handle the alert yourself (in your code). So you can check your code starting from `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` to see if you have a custom alert that is only presenting the title. (you can also edit your post to show us what you have in `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`).

Comment: I would like the local notifications for the foreground and background. I just edited my post to include my `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` code.

Comment: So at least for the foreground reception, you have complete control over the display, and what contents to show in the alert, if any. For example, you could use a UIAlertController and display a suitable alert with title, subtitle, body, ..; just add it to your `willPresent` function.